# Failure to compile because it can't find a file that exists

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

> ./src/index.js Cannot find file: 'Constants.js' does not match the
>   corresponding name on disk: './src/constants.js'

The "Constants.js" on disk has a capital 'C', so where is it getting this information from? What do I need to delete? I've re-cloned the repository and reinstalled the packages.

You want code? How about this....

```
import { AppPath } from './Constants.js'
```

[image]

Comment: i think if you screenshot Constants.js and on the left how your folder structure looks we can solve the problem! :)

Comment: @BradBall I've added a screen shot.

Comment: okay and you are trying to import from index.js?

Comment: confirm AppPath is a named export

Comment: Yes, it's a named import. It's been working ok for a while. I recently changed the case of Constants.js from constants.js.

Comment: Is there a cache somewhere for the compiler?

Comment: In the standard create-react-app config you shouldn't specify the .js extension when importing a .js(x) file

Comment: Oh found the problem. My terminal window running the server appears to have been following around an incorrect copy of the source code, even after I'd changed the name of the folder. Thanks for the help.

Comment: caught up with the same issue, :) and surprisingly VS Code ignores it